# Бекэнд для быстрой отправки файлов (тайлов карты)

Tags: node.js, файловая-система, map, tile

Необходимо сделать бекэнд для хранения тайлов карт. Размер каждого тайла 16 на 16 пикселей (изначально есть данные о цвете каждого пикселя)

Ну и как всегда стандартные требования: тайлов оочень много (1кк+), запросов тоже будет достаточно.

Посоветуйте на чем писать сие чудо и как хранить данные?
И, если можно, подскажите, почему nodejs + много png файлов - это плохо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сложно сказать точно, так как неясно общее применение, но я бы посоветовал хранить это как один большой-большой файл со всеми нужными данными. Без сжатия, оно на таких объемах профита не даст, но заставит как-то это все адресовать, т.е. делать индекс и хранить смещения + размеры.

Условно говоря, в вашей карте (я так понимаю, это будет онлайн-игра или что-то с небольшими локациями) есть двумерная адресация, и вам понадобился тайлик с координатами 555х777. Мы знаем, что вся карта 1000х1000, что дает нам как раз миллион. Считаем оффсет:

```
  смещение=(555+777*1000)*(16*16)
```

Теперь мы можем прочитать отсюда 256 байтиков и выдать клиенту. Аналогично можно и писать.

> почему nodejs + много png файлов - это плохо

nodejs плохо потому, что на нем пишут малограмотные люди, из-за которых страдает имидж той или иной технологии. По моему личному впечатлению, все кто раньше шкварил собой php, перебежали на ноду.

Много файлов - это плохо потому, что как правило на каждый файл выделяется 1 кластер/блок по 4кб (обычно, можно конечно затюнить ФС), а файлики у нас будут по 256 байт (если чернобелые) или 768 (если цветные без альфаканала). Следовательно, 4096-256 байт на файл будут потеряны, это огромная дыра дискового пространства. Еще могут кончится иноды - это когда места на диске вроде бы еще куча, а новые файлы девать некуда. Впрочем, это все можно затюнить.

Реальные проблемы начинаются на поиске - драйвер должен прочитать каждую директорию на своем пути и только потом найти нужный файл. Если все файлики сложены в одну директорию, то как правило это приводит к очень большим тормозам. Если директория размазана на кучу поддиректорий - в принципе работает лучше, но поиск никуда не девается. В случае прямой адресации ничего этого делать не надо.

ПНГ - это не плохо, но толку от сжатия такого маленького объема вы не получите, зато получите кучу заголовков и необходимость дополнптельного процессинга. В общем, не имеет смысла.

Comment: Немного дописал